# Custom Segue doesn't Play Sound

Tags: objective-c, audio, segue

I made a custom segue and I want it to play sound when changing views. Unfortunately, it doesn't. Method playSound works fine when I use it in View Controller. But i don't want to export it in every View Controller i need. How can i improve my code and why segue doesn't want to play sound?

```
#import "CustomSegue.h"
@import AVFoundation;

@interface CustomSegue()
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@end

@implementation CustomSegue
@synthesize player;
- (void) perform
{
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
    [self playSound];
}

- (void) playSound
{
    int r = arc4random_uniform(7) + 1;

    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", r] ofType:@"caf"]];
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];

    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    [self.player play];
}
```

Comment: Your sound doesn't play because the segue object is deallocated as soon as the segue finishes executing.

Comment: @rdelmar, Thank you for answer. So, there is no way i can do a custom segue like this?

Comment: Well, you could create a strong property in the source view controller for the segue (in prepareForSegue), but you would need to do that in every controller, so I don't think that's a better solution than just copying your playSound method into any controller that needs it.

Comment: @rdelmar, i was afraid of that answer. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way, but you could create a timer in your segue class. A timer keeps a strong reference to its target, so the segue object won't be deallocated until the timer is invalidated. You should invalidate the timer when your sound finishes playing (which you can do in the delegate method, audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your custom segue is released (by [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)) before the sound has a chance to play, and your audio player is released with it. [The Life Cycle of a Segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH16-SW2) is such that it is deallocated immediately after `-perform`is executed.

What you need to do is keep the audio player around for a longer time. One way to do this is to add a (strong) reference to your AVAudioPlayer from an object that is not going to be deallocated for at least as long as the sound will play. For example, place the player in your app delegate, which sticks around as long as the app is running.

Try moving the `player` property and the `-playsound` method into your app delegate. The property should look something like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

Then, in this segue, in place of `[self playsound];` make a call to the app delegate with something like:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate playsound];
```